# Backpropagation: Chain Rule for Matrix Exponential?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, chain-rule, matrix-exponential, backpropagation

Recent linear state-space model papers like Mamba often use matrix exponential to discretize the system. They initialize the system in a continuous-time regime, and discretize it to run it like a vanilla RNN / CNN.

Consider the simplest continuous-time autonomous system $d\mathbf{h(t)}/dt = A\mathbf{h(t)}$ (assuming the time constant $\tau$ = 1). $A$ is a matrix, and $\mathbf{h}$ is a vector. The discretized version of this system can be represented as $\mathbf{h}_t = exp(A)\mathbf{h}_{t-1}$ (again, assuming the discretization window $\Delta$ = 1 for simplicity). Output for loss calculation is just $\mathbf{y}_t = f(C\mathbf{h}_t)$ where f is an activation function. It can just be a linear function.

Here, I'm facing difficulty in mathematically determining how to calculate $\partial L / \partial A_{ij}$. The matrix exponential complicates the process for me. One might approximate $exp(A) \approx I + A$ but I suspect this approximation may not accurately capture the loss landscape. Does anyone have suggestions or references that could help clarify this calculation? I am not very familiar with tensor calculus so the blame is on me.

**EDIT 1**

$L$ is a loss function defined as $g(\mathbf{y}^*, \mathbf{y}_t)$. $\mathbf{y^*}$ is an optimal target. I would love to know how to correctly update the weight $A_{ij}$ regarding this loss function. Therefore, $\partial L / \partial A_{ij} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{y}_t} * \frac{\partial \mathbf{y}_t}{\partial \mathbf{h}_t} * \frac{\partial \mathbf{h}_t}{\partial A_{ij}}$ by chain rule.

I'm having trouble in calculating $\frac{\partial \mathbf{h}_t}{\partial A_{ij}}$ term.

**EDIT 2**

I realized my question can be boiled down to this:

Given $B = exp(A)$, can we express an element $B_{kl}$ with an elementary operation of A’s elements $A_{ij}$?

As my previous question is not well-structured, I may open a new question regarding an element of matrix exponential.

**EDIT 3**

My question is boiled down at [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867262/element-to-element-expression-of-a-matrix-exponential). Any further update on this question will be done at the linked post.

Also, I realized my original question did not do a very good job on indexing elements of matrix partial derivatives. Apologies on that.

Comment: Can you provide a reference, the description is not very clear.

Comment: You haven't defined $L$ in your question. If you want to differentiate a matrix exponential exactly, here is how it is done : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#Statement

Comment: @TedBlack could you please specify which part was not very clear? About discretization, [this would work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization). About state-space machine, it is not very far from a simple linear state-space model.

Comment: Ok based on this you want to look at Exercise 13.29 in "Matrix Algebra" by Abadir and Magnus. Unfortunately, there is no closed formed solution; using their notation $d(e^\mathbf{A})=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)!}\sum_{j=0}^k \mathbf{A}^j (d\mathbf{A}) \mathbf{A}^{k-j}$.

Comment: @TedBlack will check this out!