# Element-to-Element Expression of a Matrix Exponential?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Given a matrix $B = exp(A)$, how do we express $B_{ml}$ using $A_{ij}$? If $A$ is a diagonal matrix, this is very straightforward: $B_{ii} = exp(A_{ii})$. Can we generalize it to a real square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$?

Motivation: I am struggling to find an expression of $\frac{\partial B}{\partial A_{ij}} = \sum_m \sum_l \frac{\partial B_{ml}}{\partial A_{ij}}$. Knowing how to express $B_{ml}$ using $A_{ij}$ will give me a lead. If there is any other way to achieve $\sum_m \sum_l \frac{\partial B_{ml}}{\partial A_{ij}}$ without explicitly knowing $B_{ml}$, that would also be awesome.

I've looked into some old posts like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291063/derivative-of-matrix-exponential-w-r-t-to-each-element-of-the-matrix), but I am not sure if these are applicable in my case. My lack of Lie Algebra knowledge seems to be a problem here.

Comment: A standard reference is the paper of [Moler and Van Loan](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0036144502418).

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry, the link is dead. Is it this paper: **NINETEEN DUBIOUS WAYS TO COMPUTE THE EXPONENTIAL OF A MATRIX**

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Sorry, I seem to have miscopied the link: try [this](https://doi.org/10.1137/S00361445024180).

Comment: Great. The link works!

Comment: You might also want to look at [Derivative of the exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map)

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar with Lie Algebra language, but will take a time and try to digest it. Appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is not [defective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix), then it can be decomposed as
$$\eqalign{
\def\Mi{M^{-1}}  \def\Mt{M^T}  \def\Mit{M^{-T}}
\def\k{\otimes}  \def\h{\odot} \def\c{\cdot}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}     \def\l{\lambda}
\def\Diag{\operatorname{Diag}}
\def\vc{\operatorname{vec}}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
A &= M\,L\,\Mi\qquad\quad L = \Diag(\l_k) \\
}$$
and the Daleckii-Krein Theorem can be invoked to obtain the gradient
$$\eqalign{
B &= f(A) \\
dB &= M\Big(R\h\big(\Mi\,dA\,M\big)\Big)\Mi \\
\grad B{A_{ij}} &= M\Big(R\h\big(\Mi\,E_{ij}\,M\big)\Big)\Mi \\
}$$
where $(\h)$ is the Hadamard product and the components of the $E_{ij}$ matrix are all zero except for the $(i,j)$ component which is equal to one.

The components of the $R$ matrix are
$$\eqalign{
R_{k\ell}
 \;=\; \begin{cases}
  {\large\frac{f(\l_k)\,-\,f(\l_\ell)}{\l_k\,-\,\l_\ell}}\qquad{\rm if}\;\l_k\ne\l_\ell \\
\\
  \quad{\small f'(\l_k)}\qquad\qquad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
}$$
In the current problem, the function of interest is
$$ f(z) = f'(z) = \exp(z) $$

The above result can be [flattened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) into a matrix-valued gradient
$$\eqalign{
\def\R{{\large\cal D}}
a &= \vc(A),\quad b= \vc(B),
  \quad \color{red}{\R\equiv\Diag\big(\!\vc(R)\big)} \\
db &= \vc(dB) \;=\; \LR{\Mit\k M}\R\,\LR{\Mt\k\Mi}\, da \\
\grad ba &= \LR{\Mt\k\Mi}^{-1}\,\R\,\LR{\Mt\k\Mi} \\
}$$

---

A [recent paper](https://www.janmagnus.nl/papers/exponential-function.pdf) by Magnus extends this idea to defective matrices, but it is much more complicated.

On the other hand, if $A^T\!=A\,$ then the solution becomes much
simpler, since $M$ can be replaced by an **orthogonal** matrix
$$\eqalign{
\def\Qt{Q^T}  \def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
A &= Q\,L\,Q^T, \qquad \Qt = Q^{-1} \\
\grad B{A_{ij}} &= Q\Big(R\h\big(\Qt\,E_{ij}\,Q\big)\Big)\Qt \\
\grad ba &= \LR{Q\k Q}\R\,\LR{Q\k Q}^T \\
}$$

Comment: Very interesting. Appreciate this great help. With some coffee, I will read it through.

Answer (score -2):

If $A$ is diagonalisable, i.e. it can be written as $A = PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal, then we are able to say that $\exp(A) = P \exp(D) P^{-1}$. Otherwise, it is not generally possible to calculate $\exp(A)$ (and indeed it may not even have a meaningful value).

Unfortunately that also means that it is not trivial to express the elements of $\exp(A)$ in terms of the elements of $A$.

Comment: Sad, but understandable. Afaik, many computing packages like Matlab or Scipy use Pade approximation to calculate exp(A). If the distribution of $A_{ij}$ is bounded, maybe I can take a derivative of Pade approximation?

Comment: It's not at all true to say "Otherwise, it is not generally possible to calculate $\exp(A)$ (and indeed it may not even have a meaningful value)."  It is certainly well-defined, and there are many ways to calculate $\exp(A)$.  Some may be better than others, depending on the circumstances.